# Facing Error - "Cannot find file LexiLib.lxl and is needed" when connecting or disconnecting to any schema using TOAD 9.5 for Oracle 11g DB

Tags: oracle11g, toad

I had installed TOAD long time back without the 32 bit Oracle Client. Though I had installed 64 bit Oracle 11g Client, TOAD only looks for 32 bit Oracle Client because TOAD itself is a 32 bit application and only works with 32 bit Oracle Client.

So I installed Oracle Client 32 bit and I was able to logon to Database Schema. But as soon as I say connect, this below error pops up. Though am connected successfully to the schema, this error shows up time and again on some actions taken on TOAD screen. 
The file named LexiLib.lxl mentioned in error was not present in the Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\User Files folder. What I instead observed that a file with the name LexiLib.new was present there

> Error.
> Cannot find file LexiLib.lxl and is needed

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the file name present in this path - ~\Quest Software\Toad for Oracle\User Files\LexiLib.new..
from LexiLib.**new** to LexiLib.**lxl**
I referred this solution from - [here](https://amitoraebsdba.blogspot.com/search?q=LexLib.lxl) 

But..but for me this was only part of the solution perhaps because I was still facing the same error even after doing the above and re-running TOAD. So I just cut this file from the location and re-pasted it there again. I re-run TOAD and voila the error was gone.